# Determinar interfaz por propiedad dentro de objeto

Tags: typescript, interface

Mediante unión de tipos estoy tratando de determinar una interfaz entre varias.

Tengo 3 interfaces que heredan de una, llamémosle abstracta:

```
export interface AbstractWebTerm {
    history: string
    connection: connection
}
```

> **Nota**: He omitido ciertas propiedades que no son relevantes.

Luego las 3 interfaces que heredan de esta son las siguientes:

```
export interface WaitingWebTerminal extends Omit<AbstractWebTerm, 'history'> {
    connection: WaitingSshSession
}

export interface ConnectingWebTerminal extends Omit<AbstractWebTerm, 'history'> {
    connection: ConnectingSshSession
}

export interface ConnectedWebTerminal extends AbstractWebTerm {
    connection: ConnectedSshSession
}
```

Y a continuación, lo que comenté antes, hago una unión con un solo tipo:

```
export type WebTerminal = WaitingWebTerminal | ConnectingWebTerminal | ConnectedWebTerminal;
```

La propiedad `history` no debe existir en las interfaces Waiting y Connecting, pero si en Connected.

La cuestión es que lo que determina si una interfaz es una u otra es a través de una propiedad dentro del objeto `connection`, que a su vez es otra unión de tipos, pero para mantener consistentes los modelos de datos, la utilizo tanto para el servidor como el cliente:

```
// Esta interfaz se encuentra en el servidor.
export type connection = (WaitingSshSession | ConnectingSshSession | ConnectedSshSession);

export interface SshSession {
    status: 'waiting' | 'connecting' | 'connected' | 'error'
    pid?:       string
}
```

Cuando `status` equivale a `connected`, el pid debe existir, de otra manera, no, y funciona correctamente pues están al mismo nivel, pero el inconveniente es que se debe determinar si la propiedad `history` existe en base al `status`, es decir, que solo exista si `status` es equivalente a `connected`, básicamente el proceso inverso.

Con esta interfaz simplificada creo que se entiende mejor:

```
// Si status === 'connected' entonces pid existe, y la propiedad history debe existir.
export interface ConnectedWebTerminal {
    history: string // Esta propiedad debe existir a raíz del valor connected de la propiedad status que se encuentra dentro de connection.
    connection: {
        status: 'connected';
        pid: string;
    }
}
```

De manera que TypeScript no devuelva error al realizar este tipo de cosas:

```
if (terminal.connection.status === 'connected'){
    terminal.history = 'foo';
}
```

Espero haberme expresado de forma adecuada, esto es bastante complejo para lo que sé...

Comment: Como defines cual de estos tipos `export type WebTerminal = WaitingWebTerminal | ConnectingWebTerminal | ConnectedWebTerminal;` se va a usar en el código del `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nota: resuelto con ayuda de ChatGPT.**

### Ajuste del tipo `connection`

Aparentemente, las interfaces solo necesitaban un ligero ajuste en el objeto `connection`:

```
export interface WaitingWebTerminal extends Omit<AbstractWebTerm, 'history'> {
    connection: { status: 'waiting' } & WaitingSshSession
}

export interface ConnectingWebTerminal extends Omit<AbstractWebTerm, 'history'> {
    connection: { status: 'connecting' } & ConnectingSshSession
}

export interface ConnectedWebTerminal extends AbstractWebTerm {
    connection: { status: 'connected' } & ConnectedSshSession
}
```

> Bajo mi punto de vista (sin mucho fundamento), parece una unión de tipos parcial.

En este punto, los objetos literales del tipo `ConnectedWebTerminal` ya incorporaban la propiedad `history`, pero no cuando provenían de un Map.

### Problemas de inferencia y uso de type guards.

Luego había otro inconveniente, estaba usando un tipo con un genérico para usar con `WebTerminal`:

```
export type IndexedObject<T> = { [ key: string ]: T };
```

Este tipo permite declarar objetos, los cuales contienen pares de clave y valor, donde el valor es del tipo `T`, el cual será de tipo `WebTerminal`.

Este tipo lo creé para declarar el tipo de los valores de un `Map`:

```
public servers = new Map<string, IndexedObject<WebTerminal>>();
```

De forma que cuando accedía a un elemento del mapa, este contenía un objeto con varios índices, estos índices contenían un array, los cuales ya contenían un objeto de tipo `WebTerminal`.

El inconveniente radica en que TypeScript no era capaz de inferir el tipo de la unión `WebTerminal` bajo la condición del valor del status, pero exclusivamente cuando dicho objeto provenía del Map, si declara un objeto literal, la propiedad `history` existía:

```
if (term.connection.status === 'connected') {
    // En este punto, la propiedad history no existe dentro de term.
}
```

Para solucionar esto, declaré un type guard para cada una de las interfaces de las terminales, esto era una solución a la que me encontraba reacio a implementar, pero no me ha quedado de otra:

```
export const isConnectedWebTerm = (term: WebTerminal): term is ConnectedWebTerminal => {
    return term.connection.status === 'connected';
}

export const isWaitingWebTerm = (term: WebTerminal): term is WaitingWebTerminal => {
    return term.connection.status === 'waiting';
}

export const isConnectingWebTerm = (term: WebTerminal): term is ConnectingWebTerminal => {
    return term.connection.status === 'connecting';
}
```

El type guard garantizará que el tipo es correcto si la evaluación es verdadera, la cual solo necesita comprobar que la propiedad `status` es la correspondiente a cada interfaz.

Después solo era cuestión de implementar:

```
if (isConnectedWebTerm(term)) {
    term.history = '';
}
```

Finalmente Intellisense sugerirá en la lista la propiedad history, confirmando que `term` es del tipo `ConnectedWebTerminal`.

[image: Intellisense sugiriendo la propiedad history]